# read big image file as an array in python

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

Does anyone know how to open a large imagery file using python? 
I tried to open an imagery file (about 2 GB) through windows command prompt using ipython, but it crashes every time after I change image values into an array.

My laptop is window7-64bit  with 4GB ram and Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2860 QM CPU.

The error message is: python.exe has stopped working A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available

Here is my code.

```
import Image
import numpy as num
im=Image.open('myimage.tif')
imarray=num.array(im)
```

Comment: How does it crash?  Do you get a MemoryError?  What sort of feedback does python give you?

Comment: I think yes. I use numpy and Image to read in other small images successfully.

Comment: I don't know if Python can handle anything quite that large, certainly not in 32-bit mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How much RAM do you have? You'll need quite a bit more than 2GB of RAM to store a 2-gig image. I don't know how efficient `Image` is at storing images, but a list of bytes uses **four** bytes of space for each element in the list, so you'll burn more than 8GB of (virtual) memory... and a lot of patience. **Edit:** Since you only have 4 (or 3) GB to play with, this is almost certainly your problem.

But why are you trying to convert it to a numeric array? Use the methods of the `im` object returned by `Image.open`, as in the [PIL Tutorial](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/introduction.htm).

I don't know what you're doing with the image, but perhaps you can do it without reading the entire image in memory, or at least without converting the entire object into a `numpy` array. Read it bit by bit if possible to avoid blowing up your machine: Read up on python generators, and see the `Image.getdata()` method, which returns your image one pixel value at a time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about using numpy with the [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), but here's how I read the pixel data into an array (this uses a `.jpg` image). In the past this has worked well, but I don't think I've tried this with *huge* images, *so your problem may boil down to memory issues*.

```
import Image
im = Image.open('pic.jpg')

pix_ar = im.load()       # load image into 2D array
red_pixel = 255, 0, 0    # a red RGB pixel
```

and access individual elements like this:

```
x = 10
y = 5
print pix_ar[x, y]
(255, 255, 255)
```

or assign values

```
pix_ar[x, y] = red_pixel
```

***Re memory***: a 2GB image may end up taking *much* more  RAM than 2 GB once it's "unpacked" into individual pixel values, it depends on how efficient the data structures are that store this information for you once you read it into some variable/data structure. 4 GB of RAM is unlikely to be sufficient considering that you are also running the OS and some other apps concurrently while also trying to read this big file into memory.

Also, if you have successfully transferred/read files opened with the PIL to numpy in the past, the above code may not be helpful.

Comment: I tried your code, but it still crashes, when I ran im.load(). My laptop has 4GB ram. It seems not to be the problem of memory.

Comment: @VickyYan-tingLiau 4GB isn't that much if you are running the OS, other apps and trying to open a 2GB image, so it still could be an issue. What is the **exact** error message you get? Post it as part of your original question, it'll be hard to read in a comment.  It would be helpful to know more details.

Comment: @VickyYan-tingLiau You may also want to include what OS and what version. For instance Windows XP 32-bit won't let you access more than 3GB of RAM even if you have 4GB installed. You don't have that particular problem with 64-bit versions of the OS.